# Transition delay in exoplayer playlist

Tags: android, kotlin, exoplayer

Working with playlist on the ExoPlayer, I managed the setting of the playlist by following [the documentation](https://exoplayer.dev/playlists.html).

```
val firstSource = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(...).createMediaSource(firstVideoUri);
val secondSource = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(...).createMediaSource(secondVideoUri);

val playlist = ConcatenatingMediaSource(firstSource, secondSource);

player.prepare(playlist)
```

But I noticed that the transition between video is instantaneous. However, **I would like to add a waiting stage between each video, exactly like youtube does (let's say 5 sec)**. Something like:

[image: screenshot]

Is it already handled by the Exoplayer itself or not? If not what is a clean way to solve the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code.

```
object : CountDownTimer(1500, 500) {

            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                //Update your Ui.
            }

            override fun onFinish() {
                //Thats it 5 seconds gone.
            }

        }.start()
```

For more details on [CountDownTimer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer)

Comment: That would probably work if I need to do a workaround, but I would prefer a solution with the exoplayer if possible

Comment: I guess `exoplayer` doesn't provides  that type of behaviour.